# Replace DataFrame values within matching column names with Series' keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame:

```python
df = pd.DataFrame(
     [[1, 2, 3, 0, 0], [4, 5, 6, 0, 0]],
     columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

and a data series:

```python
s = pd.Series({'d': 7, 'e': 8})
```

that I need to replace the values in `df` where column names matching with the keys in `s`, i.e. `d` and `e` here, with values from `s` repeating on each `df`'s row. The desired results is:

```python
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  7  8
1  4  5  6  7  8
```

Is there an elegant pandas way to get this? Many thanks~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets use `DataFrame.assign`:

```
df.assign(**s)
```

---

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  2  3  7  8
1  4  5  6  7  8
```